# How to connect two query results?

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-9.0

I want to retrieve all ids within a certain timespan. The timestamps however,
are stored in a different table:

```
Table A has column  my_id
Table B has columns my_id, timestamp
```

I would want something like

```
SELECT
  id,
  time
FROM
  (SELECT my_id AS id FROM A) q1,
  (SELECT timestamp AS time FROM B WHERE my_id = id) q2
;
```

But how can I get the value of `id` within a different subquery? Is there
an elegant solution for this problem?

Comment: do they have different columns?

Comment: the column name in both is identical, but the data differs. i need the data from table A for ids though. i can not alter any of the databases.

Comment: It would be cleaner to have them in one table, but you can use a union (assuming there is nothing tying these two tables together)

Comment: I for one don't understand what the output should be. Can you show some sample data and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that in the second subquery you try to link the two tables:

```
(SELECT my_id AS id FROM A) q1,
(SELECT timestamp AS time FROM B WHERE my_id = id) q2
```

If both ids must be equals:

```
SELECT a.my_id as id, b.timestamp as time
FROM A a
JOIN B b ON (a.my_id = b.my_id);
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
SELECT my_id AS id, b.my_ts
FROM   a
JOIN   b USING (my_id);
```

- `FROM A a` (like has been advised) is nonsense because, I quote [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted
>   names are always folded to lower case.

- While being allowed in PostgreSQL, the type names `time` and `timestamp` are reserved words in every SQL standard and should not be used as identifiers.
- `USING` is a [syntactical shorthand, mostly](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).

Comment: This does look somewhat neater indeed. `time` and `timestamp` are not the names used in the real application. I have chosen these for my example to be unambiguous about what I am asking.